# Increasing custom variable field length piwik

Tags: matomo

I need to store an event data dump as a custom variable in piwik. But, what I realized is, piwik has a constraint that values of custom variables are set at a maximum of 200 characters in length.

Is there any way to change it? Or any workaround for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use [Custom Dimentions](https://matomo.org/docs/custom-dimensions/) instead of Custom Variables as the latter will be deprecated at some time in the future.

https://matomo.org/faq/general/faq_21117/

Unfortuntly Custom Dimentions also have a [maximum length](https://matomo.org/docs/data-limits/), but with 255 characters it is a bit longer.

Maybe at one point in the future it will be possible to save unlimited Custom Dimentions:

https://github.com/matomo-org/plugin-CustomDimensions/issues/79

https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/12348